# Change colors of scale_fill_brewer - R

Tags: r

Based on this example (https://r-graph-gallery.com/264-control-ggplot2-boxplot-colors.html, How can I change the scale_fill_brewer manually to these colors (*"#6C803A", "#7B5C34", "#AB7C47", "#CCAE42", "#D73202",  "#272318", "#D3CDBF")*?

code:

```
library(ggplot2)
 
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=class, y=hwy, fill=class)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.3) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_manual(values = ...)` if you want to use custom colors.